# Pandas Read CSV file with variable rows to skip with special character at the beginning of row

Tags: python, csv, pandas

When reading a CSV file using pandas, read_csv method, how do I skip the lines if the number of lines are not known in advance ?

I have a CSV file which contains some meta-data at the beginning of the file and then contains the header and actual data.

- The meta data always start with a **#** sign and it would always be at the top of CSV file.
- The number of lines for meta data is not fixed.

Example for the file **sample_file.csv**:

```
# Meta-Data Line 1
# Meta-Data Line 2
# Meta-Data Line 3
col1,col2,col3
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

How would I use Pandas read_csv function and skiprows parameter to read the csv ?

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample_file.csv', skiprows=?)
```

Does Pandas 0.19.X or greater support this use case ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`comment` is what you're searching for:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample_file.csv', comment='#')
```

From the documentation:

> comment : str, default None
>
> Indicates remainder of line should not be
>   parsed. If found at the beginning of a line, the line will be ignored
>   altogether. This parameter must be a single character. Like empty
>   lines (as long as skip_blank_lines=True), fully commented lines are
>   ignored by the parameter header but not by skiprows. For example, if
>   comment=’#’, parsing ‘#emptyna,b,cn1,2,3’ with header=0 will result in
>   ‘a,b,c’ being treated as the header.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Comment: love the comment=, but i have a csv with +160k rows. i need to comment out about half of them. even sublime text flips out when i try to use multitple cursors. isn't there set what line to start at instead?

Comment: as indicated in the doc above, skiprows will start parsing after skipping a lines at the beginning, but you have to make sure you know a certain minimum lines to skip. Not sure why comment is not enough to use